# Intel i3/i5 AIO with wall mount

Tags: wifi, windows, all-in-one

I'm looking for an All-in-One device. It should have Win10 Pro installed. I would prefer an Intel i5 or i3 processor.

The special requirement is the wall mount. The only device I found weights 12kg. Maybe someone knows a lighter device. It should have VESA for an easy installation.

What is your budget? 400-900€

What are you planning on doing with it (video editing, gaming, running some server applications, etc)? Casual Office work and using RDP.

How big should the screen be, and what resolution would you like? 20-24"

Comment: This is way too broad of a question.

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recs! Unfortunately, this question is a bit broad. Would you mind editing your question to answer the following questions please? What is your budget? What are you planning on doing with it (video editing, gaming, running some server applications, etc)? How big should the screen be, and what resolution would you like? The more details that you give us, the better we will be able to help you.